# "What do you think …." constructions

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives

I am very confused regarding the use of *What/how/etc. do you think ...* as questions.

e.g.:

> 1. *What do you think is my name?*
> 2. *What do you think my name is?*

and,

> 3. *How do you think it is done?*
> 4. *How do you think is it done?*

and also,

> 5. *Does anyone remember how we connected to the server?*
> 6. *Does anyone remember how did we connect to the server?*

Can you please elaborate with grammatical rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When asking a question like this, think of how you would answer the question.

---

**Correct:**

> [What do you think] [my name is]?

The answer is, "[My name is] Keiki."

> [How do you think] [it is done]?

The answer is, "[It is done] like this."

> [Does anyone remember how] [we connected to the server]?

The answer is, "[We connected to the server] like this."

---

**Incorrect:**

> [What do you think] [is my name]?

"[Is my name] Keiki," is another question, not an answer.

> [How do you think] [is it done]?

"[Is it done] like this," is another question, not an answer.

> [Does anyone remember how] [did we connect to the server]?

"[Did we connect to the server] like this," is another question, not an answer.

---

I can't tell you the technical term for why this is correct, and like all rules, there are probably exceptions, but I think it's pretty easy to remember like this.

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider your first sentence -

Changing it into assertive sentence it looks like this -

> You think Tom is my name.

*what* is the substitute of *Tom*.

> You think *what* is my name.

Now change it into interrogative sentence -

> What do you think is my name?

Another way to say this sentence is -

> You think my name is Tom.
>
> You think my name is *what*.

Now changing it into interrogative sentence -

> What do you think my name is? (In my opinion this is better)

[Name are usually not people, so it's *what*, not *who*.]

Consider your second sentence - (Changing it into assertive sentence)

> You think it is done in a careful way.

*how* is the substitute of *in a careful way*

> You think it is done *how*.

Inverting subject-verb to form a question -

> How do you think it is done?

I think the following sentence is wrong -

> *How do you think is it done? (INCORRECT)

Your third sentence. Changing it into assertive sentence -

> Anyone remembers we connected to the server in a difficult way.

Forming question -

> Does anyone remember how we connected to the server?

The following sentence is incorrect -

> *Does anyone remember how did we connect to the server? (INCORRECT)

Comment: The *anyone* in your last few examples is a negative polarity item.  It can appear in negation: "I didn't see **anyone (at all).**" And in questions: "Did you see **anyone (at all)?**"  But not: \*"I saw **anyone**."  You can use *someone* instead: "I saw **someone**."

Comment: @snailboat nods. What I was trying there in these sentences is to retain almost the same words for demonstration purpose. So that shifting the *wh-words* and inverting the subject-verb arrangement a question can be formed.